# How to clear overlap the uilabel and uiimageview in reload uitableview?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitableview

I want to show in the -

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I create at run time `uiimage` and `uilabel1` and `uilabel2` these are show as my array count=5.

these 5 items to be show like this way:

in the 1st row of the table 3items shown.and remained 2 items to be shown in the next now.

this is to work while load the table view.

then i change the run time array count=7.
i try to reload the tableview.
in the tableview overlap on the old array count 5 value.

How can i solve this problem ?

please give idea to solve this problem,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to understand your question if you provide some code. Are your adding a subview to the cell? If yes, this will probably solve your problem:

```
if ([cell.contentView subviews]){
    for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```